# What is the dispatcher priority given to the action when you call Dispatcher.Invoke(Action)?

Tags: c#, dispatcher

What is the dispatcher priority given to the action when you call Dispatcher.Invoke(Action)?

I understand how Dispatcher.Invoke(Action, DispatcherPriority) works, I assume that if you leave out the DispatcherPriority parameter it will give the action a default DispatcherPriority  value. Am I wrong? If no what is that default value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can look in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,078d6b27d9837a35) from Microsoft directly in the source code.

It is using [`DispatcherPriority.Send`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority(v=vs.110).aspx).

The reference source comes pretty handy for cases like this.